# Custom user HTML input safety

Tags: javascript, php, html, security

I am creating a website in php. One of the features is that users can edit their own pages by entering custom html code. Right now, you can enter code into a textarea and have it displayed in a div. In the future I plan on adding more helpful tools to the user.

My question is how to protect my site from malicious code. I know Facebook has an option to put custom HTML in a page tab so it can be done safely. Currently, the html is being displayed by a php script that echos it onto a page so users can enter javascript in `<script>` tags as well. I don't know the full limits of javascript and html but I know that custom javascript embedded into the website has the potential to screw things up.

Here are my ideas so far:

- Remove all javascript from user code

  - Pros: Easy
  - Cons: Users can't do anything interesting with javascript
- Limit the javascript to only execute inside the display div

  - Pros: Safe custom javascript
  - Cons: May be impossible/very difficult

If anyone has ideas about how to do this or how Facebook did this, I would love to know! Thanks in advance.

Comment: If they're allowing Javascript, they almost certain are putting it in an `iframe` so that it won't have any access to the main page.

Comment: I would put it in an iFrame but I want the html to have no css constraints from being inside an iframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using php, an excellent solution is to use HTMLPurifier. It has many options to filter out bad stuff, and as a side effect, guarantees well formed html output.

Comment: @Harrison: You should use it in combination with a Content Security Policy just in case any vulnerabilities in HTMLPurifier are found in future: http://security.stackexchange.com/a/61134/8340